# C# Date Manipulation to filter users

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

How can I get the date for:

- Last three **months**
- Last year

The reason for this is that I want to compare all user creation dates and check if the user registered within the last three weeks or last year.

In a C# ASP.NET Website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will you filter data from front end or at database end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Last three months

  ```
  DateTime threeMonthsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)
  ```
- Last year

  ```
  DateTime oneYearAgo = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
  ```

Then you could compare the `DateTime` instance with `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, but I meant last three months my mistake sorry. So i'm guessing .AddMonths(-3) ?

Comment: Sure, no problem, answer updated. Yes, you are guessing right, you could use `DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-3)`.

Comment: One more question, what is the difference between DateTime.Now and .Today ?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` contains the time portion, whereas `DateTime.Today` doesn't (the time is set to 00:00:00 with `DateTime.Today`).